# Where does the "demo" module go?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am trying to get some example of how the "gnuplot" haskell wrapper works, and I followed the [instructions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gnuplot-0.5) of installing it with examples from cabal:

```
cabal install -fbuildExamples gnuplot
```

They say that "Examples for using this interface can be found in the Demo module."
But where is this demo module located? I am on Windows 7, using Haskell platform.

Any tips, welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be found in the source code of the package. The easiest way to get it is to use the `cabal unpack` commmand, which downloads the source code of a package.

```
$ cd ~/Code                           # or whereever you want it
$ cabal unpack gnuplot
Downloading gnuplot-0.4.2...
Unpacking to gnuplot-0.4.2/
$ vim gnuplot-0.4.2/src/Demo.hs       # or whatever editor you're using
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Even thought the stupid examples still don't work, but that is another question...